# In Settings > Apps, where can I find the app called "Recommended apps?

Tags: samsung, android-12

Where on Settings > Apps, can I find the app that identifies itself elsewhere as "Recommended apps"?

I get notifications from an app that Settings > Notifications IDs as "Recommended apps" but Settings > Apps shows no such app.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this problem? Are you not able to hide or uninstall the app which is creating these notifications to begin with?

Comment: "Can you post a screenshot of this problem?" That would be nothing but a screenshot of Settings > Apps showing no "Recommended apps"... so not useful I think.

Comment: Perhaps screenshotting the notification panel with the "Recommended apps" notification, and then trying to long-press the notification might give some hints.

Comment: Have you ticked the "show system apps"? A lot of apps (on Samsung most likely 100 or more) are hidden there by default. ou ould alo try searching for "rcommended" in Settings. Or if all those "recommendations" lead to the Samsung Store (app), check there (or disable it if you don't use it).

Comment: "Have you ticked the "show system apps"?" No. I never even saw it. But now I find it under Settings > Apps > Your Apps > sort icon (!) and it does answer the question. Thanks, Please post an Answer so I can accept.

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [How do I uninstall the "Recommended apps" app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248995/44325)